# Is it possible make up Formula in Excel to Find substring in range cells and return the finded cell's value?

Tags: excel, range, formula, cell, vlookup

is it possible to find substring from second column in first column and insert in third column like that (vlookup doesn't):

| Column values | What find | This is found |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | eco | Second |
| Second | irst | First |
| Third | eond | Don't find |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be possible using VLOOKUP. If everything was pasted in Excel as is (with headers) the formula displaying Second would be:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP("*"&B2&"*";$A$2:$A$4;1;FALSE);"Don't find")
```

You can drag it down and it will be good for the other ones also, if it doesn't find the value it will create an error which is catched by the IFERROR and thus showing Don't Find instead.

Answer (score 2):

With `Excel365`, `XLOOKUP()` would be best case using `wildcard character match` option to `[search_mode]` argument.

```
=XLOOKUP("*"&B2&"*",$A$2:$A$4,$A$2:$A$4,"Don't find",2)
```

[image]

Also `INDEX/MATCH()` will work for prior version.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$4,MATCH("*"&B2&"*",$A$2:$A$4,0)),"Don't find")
```